# Antenna Gain diagram to power diagram

Tags: antenna

I have a 3d gain diagram from an antenna. How can I calculate the power of this antenna?

Thanks!

Comment: More detail is needed... what are you looking for? Effective Isotropic Radiated Power (EIRP)? Directivity? Total radiated power?

Comment: I have a phased array with some power. I want to check if my 3D gain diagram matches the phased array power

Comment: Show all details

Comment: Is this a homework? When you have a 3D model... isn't power equal to geometric volume?

Answer (score 0):

If used as specified the output power = Pin + 3dB . This means rather than rather than isotopic= spherical pattern, it radiates twice this power in one direction above ground plane or half of a sphere , usually in a toroidal (donut like) intensity 3D pattern with a null in the axial direction.